# Mouse clicks not registering on the right monitor

Tags: unity, mouse, monitor

Exactly the same as this: [Mouse mysteriously stops working on my right-hand screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/568078/mouse-mysteriously-stops-working-on-my-right-hand-screen)

Working with an Acer Aspire V15, Ubuntu 16.04. I have a second, larger Dell monitor to the left, attached through VGA.

Randomly -- and I can't see what might be triggering this -- mouse clicks will completely stop working in the right monitor. It doesn't matter which of the 4 virtual windows I switch to: all mouse clicks are not registered, except those in the Launch bar to the left, or the bar at the top.

As pointed out in the linked thread, `unity --replace` fixes this, as does logging out. Disconnecting the second monitor also fixes this, but the issue immediately returns when it is reconnected. Changing the position of the monitors also works, but I am at a fixed workstation so I cannot actually do this.

How do I prevent this from happening, or go about debugging it? `unity --replace` means I have to start up my browser and Eclipse all over again, which is ultra inefficient.